# Applying templates to XML with namespace

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following XML data:

```
<main xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <section>
        <value>s1</value>
    </section>
    <section>
        <value>s2</value>
    </section>
</main>
```

and XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <page>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="/main/section" />
        </page>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="section">
        <test section="{value}" />
    </xsl:template>        
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The output I'm expecting is the following:

```
<page>
    <test section="s1" />
    <test section="s2" />
</page>
```

But I'm getting:

```
<page xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"/>
```

I've tested this using [this online tool](http://xslttest.appspot.com/). Obviously I'm doing something wrong, but it's late and I can't wrap my head around this. Could you suggest a way for me to fix this problem?

---

To be a bit more precise: I cannot name the namespace of the XML data, therefore the answer to the suggested duplicate does not solve this problem.

Comment: "*I cannot name the namespace of the XML data,*" What do you mean by that? The namespace URI is `"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"` and the prefix can be anything you like.

Comment: @michael.hor257k I mean that I can't add a namespace prefix to the XML. This is because I'm using a DOMDocument object in JavaScript.

Comment: "*I can't add a namespace prefix to the XML.*" You're not supposed to modify the XML in any way; it's all done in the XSLT stylesheet. Read more carefully.

Comment: @michael.hor257k You're totally right, should've paid better attention. Thank you!